# How to use Angular SearchPipe and separate the components

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, I want to create a simple search filter that uses an input tag to search for a book in this case, as things are this works but I want to separate the components, and when I do this the search filter no longer works. No errors, just not working as expected.

This is my app.component.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <!-- <app-search-bar (searchTextChanged)="searchText=$event"></app-search-bar> -->
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchText">
  <div *ngFor="let e of words | search: searchText">
    <p>{{ e.word }}</p>
    <ol>
      <li *ngFor="let meaning of e.meanings">{{ meaning }}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'DictionaryTwo';
  words = [
    {
        "word": "book",
        "meanings": [
            "a written or printed work consisting of pages glued or sewn together along one side and bound in covers",
            "to reserve something for a particular purpose, such as a hotel room or a table at a restaurant"
        ]
    },
    // rest of the array items
    {
      "word": "bat",
      "meanings": [
          "a nocturnal flying mammal that feeds on insects, typically having a leathery skin and sharp teeth",
          "a piece of wood used to hit a ball in various games"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "run",
      "meanings": [
          "to move at a speed faster than walking, usually with both or all feet off the ground at the same time",
          "to manage or operate (a business or organization)"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "plant",
      "meanings": [
          "a living organism that typically grows in the ground and has a stem, leaves, and roots",
          "to put something in the ground to grow"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "key",
      "meanings": [
          "a small piece of metal that is used to lock or unlock a door, start a car, or activate a machine",
          "a button or lever on a musical instrument, typewriter, or computer keyboard"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "scale",
      "meanings": [
          "a device for weighing things, typically consisting of a spring and a metal platform",
          "a series of graduated markings for measuring or rating something"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "play",
      "meanings": [
          "engage in activity for enjoyment and recreation rather than a serious or practical purpose",
          "a dramatic work for the stage or to be broadcast"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "mouse",
      "meanings": [
          "a small rodent that typically has a pointed snout, relatively large ears and eyes, and a long tail",
          "a handheld device used to move a cursor on a computer screen"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "band",
      "meanings": [
          "a thin strip or loop of material used to fasten or hold something",
          "a group of musicians who play music together"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "box",
      "meanings": [
          "a container with a flat base and sides, typically square or rectangular and having a lid",
          "to fight an opponent in a boxing match"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "charge",
      "meanings": [
          "to demand that someone pay for something, typically as a result of a legal judgment",
          "to rush forward in attack"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "pipe",
      "meanings": [
          "a tube of metal, plastic, or other material used to convey water, gas, oil, or other fluid substances",
          "a musical instrument played by blowing air through it"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "bar",
      "meanings": [
          "a long, narrow piece of metal or wood",
          "a place where alcoholic drinks are served"
      ]
  },
  {
      "word": "play",
      "meanings": [
          "engage in activity for enjoyment and recreation rather than a serious or practical purpose",
          "a dramatic work for the stage or to be broadcast"
      ]
  }
]
  searchText = '';
}
```

And this is the app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SearchBarComponent } from './search-bar/search-bar.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SearchPipe } from './search.pipe';
import { DisplayContentComponent } from './display-content/display-content.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchBarComponent,
    SearchPipe,
    DisplayContentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I want to split the Search bar and the for-loop content into two separate components: `search-bar` and `display-content` respectively.

To test this for yourself, you'll have to run the `ng g pipe Search` command to install Angular SearchPipe.

**Edit: Code for the SearchPipe**
search.pipe.spec.ts

```
import { SearchPipe } from './search.pipe';

describe('SearchPipe', () => {
  it('create an instance', () => {
    const pipe = new SearchPipe();
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

search.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(!value)return null;
    if(!args)return value;

    args = args.toLowerCase();
    return value.filter((item: any) =>{
      return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(args)
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: you probably want a ViewChild in order to pass data & events back and forth between 2 components.

Comment: What is the code for your pipe..?

Comment: @MikeOne I added the code for the SearchPipe.